# Abelian twisted reduced group C*-algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $G$ be an abelian discrete group. Then is $C_r^*(G, \sigma)$ abelian?

Comment: Can't you write the irrational rotation algebras $\mathcal A_\theta$ as $C^\ast_r(\mathbb Z^2, \sigma)$ for a twist $\sigma$?

Comment: There is a twisted group ring of $Z/p\times Z/p$ isomorphic to $p\times p$ matrices over $\mathbb C$

Comment: @JamieGabe What is sigma here?

Comment: I think $\sigma((m_1,m_2), (n_1, n_2)) = exp(2\pi i m_2 n_1 \theta)$ for $(m_1,m_2), (n_1,n_2) \in \mathbb Z^2$ defines the right 2-cocycle.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simplest possible noncommutative example.  We can realize $M_2(\mathbb C)$ as a twisted group ring of the Klein four group.  Let $\overline e =\begin{bmatrix} 1& 0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$, $\overline a = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$, $\overline b = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 1& 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\overline{c} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & -1\\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.  These matrices form a basis for $M_2(\mathbb C)$ and you can check that these matrices multiply like in a Klein $4$-group up to a sign giving the twist.  The corresponding $2$-cocycle $\sigma$ has $\sigma(a,a)=\sigma(b,b)=\sigma(a,b)=1$.  Note that $\sigma(b,a) =-1$.  I leave it as an exercise to compute the values of $\sigma$ involving $c$.  In any event, $M_2(\mathbb C)\cong C_r^*(V,\sigma)$ where $V$ is the Klein four group.